# Why did I get suspended for 6 days with all my votes reversed?

Tags: support, serial-voting, account-suspension

So in Chemistry and Math Stack Exchange I got suspended for six days and got my votes reversed. I believe that is because the moderators thought that I voted for myself.

So basically what was happening was that this account, John Rawls, had this other account Nick Bostrom voting for John Rawls. But rather I know Nick Bostrom so I kept on facebooking him the links to my questions so that I can get an answer.

I was wondering whether I am going to get my points back for Math.SE and Chem.SE after six days. If not, I was wondering if I could get it reversed because I don't understand why this is happening and I believe that this is unfair.

This question is specific and should not be marked as duplicate because this is a scenario where someone is voting for me

Comment: who? this guy [Nick Bostrom](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/39689/nick-bostrom) he has not answered a single question.

Comment: He answered a few math and chem questions, to clarify he does sometimes but most of the time he can't answer it (no offense to nick) so i think he just up votes. I texted him and he said that he uprooted a few of them.

Comment: So why can't I see his answers and also he doesn't exist on math stack exchange if you have more proof that he legitimately answer your questions and in turn upvote the questions then edit it in your question and ask him to restrain upvoting serially at a time.

Comment: The weird thing is that Nick Bostrom can't even vote, not on any site. So there has to be another user they think is voting for you.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar that [Nick Bostrom](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/39689/nick-bostrom) looks like he joined Math.SE and Chemistry.SE today! Definitely there is something else about that situation.

Comment: You've been suspended because the system and/or experienced moderators detected an issue in tour voting patterns. You have been set to 1 reputation for the duration because that's how it works. You will get the rest back, plus-minus interim changes, when the suspension finishes.

Comment: I believe That Nick Bostrom got banned forever on math stack exchange

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289555/204841

Comment: So hang about. You're John Rawls, and you claim to know someone called Nick Bostrom who answered some of your questions (?), but definitely isn't serially upvoting you or a sockpuppet that you control. Correct?

Comment: If that's the case, why is [your account on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/156853/bostrom-nick) called "bostrom nick"? I'm afraid to say that makes me *very* suspicious.

Comment: @ArtOfCode heh, busted. Area 51 for the rescue. LOL.

Answer (score 8):

As answered in the other question it seems the two accounts of you were that tightly related (only answering and voting on each other) that a moderator assumed the two of you have a voting ring.

Since [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/245360) (or voting on a specific user only) is not allowed, the moderator deleted the other user's account and suspended yours.

The lesson is: don't just vote on one user. Also try to be open to other users. Be careful when sharing your posts with other users on social media.