# Why did my account disappear?

Tags: support, account-suspension, deleted-accounts

My Account disappeared yesterday from math and chem stack exchange.

I am very confused what happened was that I was told something strange happened to my account and I logged in and sure enough I have 1 reputation point on chem stack exchange and my math stack exchange got deleted.

Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: This might help you http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289554/why-did-i-get-suspended-for-6-days-with-all-my-votes-reversed

Answer (score 7):

[Why did I get suspended for 6 days with all my votes reversed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289554) seems to indicate that you were thought to be a [sock puppet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/245360) of the user account referenced there.

A moderator investigated the case and it seemed to the moderator that the two of you had a voting ring. Probably you answered all of the other user's question, upvoting the other user's questions, etc. If users are that tightly coupled, it usually means there is something wrong.

You could flag a question or answer and explain to a moderator what actually happened. They then can investigate what happened.

Comment: Flagging for moderator attention probably won't be worth it. When an account is deleted, site moderators no longer have access to _all_ the information used to determine whether one is/was a sockpuppet of another (and for myself it _always_ goes beyond simple voting statistics). If anyone still has access to the full picture, it would be the CMs, who can be [contacted directly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).